# Coinbase API invalid request (oauth token)

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

I am trying to use the **Coinbase API for oauth**, but keep getting an invalid request response *"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."*

Following their guide https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/integrating, I'm able to:

1. Successfully redirect users to request Coinbase access

GET https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&state=SECURE_RANDOM&scope=wallet:accounts:read

2. Successfully have Coinbase redirects back to your site

GET https://example.com/oauth/callback?code=4c666b5c0c0d9d3140f2e0776cbe245f3143011d82b7a2c2a590cc7e20b79ae8&state=134ef5504a94
app://oauth-coins?code=4c666b5c0c0d9d3140f2e0776cbe245f3143011d82b7a2c2a590cc7e20b79ae8

3. Unsuccessfully exchange code for an access token
   POST https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token")! //
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.setValue("authorization_code", forHTTPHeaderField: "grant_type")
   request.setValue("\(self.code)", forHTTPHeaderField: "code")
   request.setValue("clientid1234", forHTTPHeaderField: "client_id")
   request.setValue("clientsecret1234", forHTTPHeaderField: "client_secret")
   request.setValue("app://oauth-coins", forHTTPHeaderField: "redirect_uri")
   ```

Because I get an error return in the `json`:

```
{
    error = "invalid_request";
    "error_description" = "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.";
}
```

**UPDATE (solved):**

I needed to not `setValue` for all of the parameters, but to post them as the `request.httpBody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to not `setValue` for all of the parameters, but to post them as the `request.httpBody`